# One or two ads depending on window width - is it possible?

Tags: html, css, adsense

I was hoping you could help me with this one, since I know little about HTML, CSS, etc. Essentially, me and my friends have a website ( https://www.mitologia.pt/ ), and we are using Adsense. At the bottom of the page we want to add a Matched Ad, together with a Display Ad, but for now one is after the other (which looks horrible). Instead, we wanted to do it like this:

- If the window width is under 500px, only the Matched Ad should be seen;
- If the window width is over 500px, regardless of the window size we wanted to present a 300x250 Display ad on the right side, and use all the remaining space for a Matched Ad (on the left).

Is it possible to do this? If so, how? Here's my current solution, which works perfectly for over 500px, but doesn't work at all for under it...

```
    <div style="margin-top: -12px; float: left; width: calc(100% - 300px);">
<!-- Recommendations -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-format="autorelaxed"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="YYY"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script> <br />
 </div>
 <!-- THIS IS FOR THE AD ON THE RIGHT -->
 <div style="margin-top: -12px; float: right; width: 300px;">
 <!-- fim da página -->
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display:inline-block; width: 300px; height: 250px; }
@media (max-width:500px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
@media (min-width:500px) { .adslot_1 { width: 300px; height: 250px; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
   data-ad-client="XXX"
   data-ad-slot="YYY"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script> <br />
 </div>
```

Comment: Read a little about @media for example from here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp and if any problems comes, just add what did you try to do and it didn't work

Comment: @Kida, I just added my current solution to the initial post. It works perfectly for over 500px, but doesn't work for under it...

Comment: Without working snippet from you code **I'm just guessing**, but first your `@media` max-width is the same as min-width, so they may overwrite each other. I would try to change one of them for example for max-width 501px. Another issue may be order of  your `@media`, maybe it should be min-width first. And the last maybe you should use !important next to new width values to be sure that any other css style not overwrite your `@media`

Comment: @Kida, fortunately all that is working right now. My big problem is that in devices under 500px, the left side's size is still being calculated as "calc(100% - 300px)". I sort of need a conditional here, I guess... but I'm not very good at these things. :(

Comment: Hmm it seems like `!important` will not overwrite your inline written style. Maybe try to make a class in css `.calculated {width: calc(100% - 300px);}` and add this class to div instead of inline styling. And then if you have `!important` in your `@media` you can put the same class with changed value and it should nicely overwrite it

Comment: @Kida , maybe I should tell you that seems all like chinese to me. I don't know much about any of these things... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Kida , I was able to finally fix this. Here is the final code, since it may help someone else in the future:

```
<div class='leftBottomAd' style="float: left;">
<style type="text/css">
    .leftBottomAd { width: calc(100% - 300px); }
    @media (max-width:800px){ .leftBottomAd { width: 100% !important;}}
</style>
<!-- Recommendations -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-format="autorelaxed"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="YYY"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>  </div>

<div style="float: right; width: 300px;">
 <!-- Bottom Ad -->
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display:inline-block; width: 300px; height: 250px; }
@media (max-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 300px; height: 250px; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
   data-ad-client="XXX"
   data-ad-slot="YYY"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script> <br/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so that's your inline styled div:

```
<div style="margin-top: -12px; float: left; width: calc(100% - 300px);">
```

My idea is to try this:

```
<div class='yourNameOfClass' style="margin-top: -12px; float: left;">
<style type="text/css">
    .yourNameOfClass
    {
       width: calc(100% - 300px);
    }
    @media (max-width:500px) 
    {
      .yourNameOfClass
      {
         width: /*wharever you wish here*/!important;
      }
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that I can't see any ads on your website, so I can't imagine problem accurately

Comment: thank you for your help! I had to do some extra coding changes, but eventually your solution made it all work!